# Disable auto tooltip when hover cursor on vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, tooltip

Okay, I tried this already but still not working.

```js
editor.hover.enabled: false
```

[image]

This is so annoying.
Someone help me turn of this tip box...Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting "editor.parameterHints.enabled": false in your settings.json

Comment: Hi. I just turn off  editor.hover:sticky. I tried your comment too. Thanks tho!

Answer (score 0):

Using a delay will allow you still see tips without such annoyance...

`"editor.hover.delay": 1500`